# PHP inline if statement always returns false

Tags: php, if-statement, inline

can't seem to start this working properly, any idea what could be the problem? The variable APP_NAME is equal to string 'test', if I do this if statement in a regular way it works as it should.

```
<?=form_radio('filter', 'y', $info['enable_categories'] == 'y' ? true : false, 'id="app" '.APP_NAME == "test" ? '' : 'disabled'.'')?>
```

The disabled parameter has to be put into the same last parameter as id.

But this way I get the false value even if APP_NAME equals 'test'.

The function form_radio has these parameters:

`function form_radio($data = '', $value = '', $checked = FALSE, $extra = '')`
so the extra parameter has to be ID and also the "disabled" string if the value is not equal to 'test'.

Comment: You pass this as parameter?

Comment: As constant, as I wrote it.

Comment: you pass this: $info['enable_categories'] == 'y' ? true : false, 'id="app" '.APP_NAME == "test" ? '' : 'disabled'.'' as parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
'id="app" '.APP_NAME == "test" ? '' : 'disabled'.''
```

the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) makes this evaluate as

```
('id="app" '.APP_NAME) == "test" ? '' : 'disabled'.''
```

So you should use parentheses around the ternary clause:

```
'id="app" '.(APP_NAME == "test" ? '' : 'disabled'.'')
```

You can also get rid of the `.''`. Also the clause

```
$info['enable_categories'] == 'y' ? true : false
```

can be simplified to

```
$info['enable_categories'] == 'y'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. :)